# Convert timezone on Sqlalchemy get()

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, timezone

I am messing around with timezones in a Flask application using Sqlalchemy (with Postgres). Postgres saves datetime as timestamps with time zone, and all datetimes are stored in UTC by default. Using python's Pendulum library its easy to convert to different timezones.

I have a simple sqlalchemy-based model:

```
class Order(Model): 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String(10))
    order_date = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))
```

I would like to convert the `order_date` of an `Order` - identified by an `order_id` - to the user's timezone upon query. I can do (I assume `user.timezone` is a valid timezone):

```
order = db.session.query(id, 
                         code,
                         func.timezone(user.timezone, Order.order_date).label('order_date'))\
          .filter(Order.id == order_id)\
          .first()
```

but sometimes it is easier to just `get` the `Order`:

```
order = Order.query.get(order_id)
```

In this latter way, I get the stored UTC `order_date`. It is possible to convert the `order_date` using the `get` function?

My workaround is to `get` the object, go through the model's fields (assuming that in real cases an object may have more than one datetime field) and, if a field is a `datetime`, convert it to the user's timezone as follows:

```
import datetime
import pendulum

def convert_tz(obj, tz):
    for each in obj.__dict__:
        d = getattr(obj, each)
        if isinstance(d, datetime.datetime):
            setattr(obj, each, tz.convert(d))

order = Order.query.get(order_id)
tz = pendulum.timezone(user.timezone)
convert_tz(order, tz)
```

It seems working but also seems too convoluted. Is there a better way?
Thanks

Comment: I'd advise to take a step back, and consider what your intention for converting the timezone is. You just want to display it in a user-friendly manner in your Flask app, then I'd say a [template filter](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/templating/#registering-filters) would be more appropriate. If you intend operations on the order date, maybe a [hybrid method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @bgse For displaying the data the template filter suggestion is good indeed. However, I am considering to do the conversion in the view (and not in the template) because the object is used to populate a form allowing to change the data. Thanks for pointing out the hybrid methods.

Comment: If you want to do it on the postgres side, you can wrap your queries with a  `SET LOCAL TIME ZONE 'GMT'` . This will set the timezone for the current transaction only.

Comment: @clamp Seems an interesting approach, could you please provide an example of wrapping the queries?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use sqlalchemy, but according to the docs at `https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#what-does-the-session-do` it could be easy as `session = Session() // session.execute(SET LOCAL TIME ZONE 'GMT') // do stuff // session.commit()` plus errorhandling etc.

Comment: I have the same problems. I tried your solution, but why I can't find ``func.timezone`` function?

Comment: @gotounix: from sqlalchemy import func